# How to sign out a user in ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to log out all active sessions of a user that I am changing (deleting, adding or removing roles, changing the password etc.).

I found solutions for old versions of ASP .NET. Essentially calling `UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(userId);` but this doesn't seem to work with ASP .NET Core. I can call the function, but it just does nothing. The user is still logged in after that.

So how on earth can I log out a logged in user (all open sessions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property of `IdentityOptions` called  `SecurityStampValidationInterval`, which sets how often the cookie is validated. Its set to 30 minutes by default. You can change that:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
     options.SecurityStampValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);             
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works perfectly. Are there any performance penalties when using such a low value? At what times is the stamp actually validated when setting this property to 1 tick? (only once per request I guess).

Comment: @FSMaxB  Yes there are. Each an extra request to database on every HTTP request from a user.

Comment: So there really isn't any other way to invalidate the user cookie? We can't change the data protection key for that user cookie or do something that invalidates the cookie in memory?

Setting the stamp validation interval seems like a workaround and defeats the purpose of having this style of identity in the first place.

Answer (score -4):

Create the scaffold item for Account/logout and amend the `post` function as needed or create a `get` function to emulate what the `post` one does which is basically calls `await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();`